# group-ending-with - where is my text gone?

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm struggling with some basic xslt grouping, but fail to understand where things go wrong. Take below xml snapshot :

```
<ul>
<li>This is a text only node</li>
<li>This one contains some different ones, like an  <img src="#" alt="dummy" />image and a break.<br />Also a link <a href="#"> for testing purposes</a>.</li>
<li>This one contains some different ones, like an  <img src="#" alt="dummy" />image but no break. Also a link <a href="#"> for testing purposes</a>.</li>
</ul>
```

What I like to achieve is that for every [li] that contains a break the content before the break get's wrapped, if it doesn't contain a break the whole content gets wrapped. So wanted outcome would be as follows :

```
<ul>
<li>
    <string>This is a text only node</string>
</li>
<li>
    <string>This one contains some different ones, like an  <img src="#" alt="dummy" />image and a break.</string>
    <br/>
    <string>Also a link <a href="#"> for testing purposes</a>.
</li>
<li>
    <string>This one contains some different ones, like an  <img src="#" alt="dummy"/>image but no break. Also a link <a href="#"> for testing purposes</a>.</string>
</li>
```

This is the xslt I have in place

```
    <xsl:template match="li">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="br">
        <!-- node contains a break so let's group -->
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="br">
                <!-- copy all but the break -->
                <string><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[not(self::br)]"/></string>
                <!-- and place break unless it's the last element, then we don't need it... -->
                <xsl:if test="not(position() = last())"><br/></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <string><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/></string>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But this seems to strip my text also, which isn't what I want... output I get is as follows :

```
<ul>
<li>
    <string>This is a text only node</string>
</li>
<li>
    <string>
        <img src="#" alt="dummy"/>
    </string>
    <br/>
    <string>
        <a href="#"> for testing purposes</a>
    </string>
</li>
<li>
    <string>This one contains some different ones, like an  <img src="#" alt="dummy"/>image but no break. Also a link <a href="#"> for testing purposes</a>.</string>
</li>
```

So it strips my text from current-group(). What am i overlooking here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you need to process all child nodes with `<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-ending-with="br">` instead of processing simply the element child nodes as you currently do.